# PHP - Delete on button click not working

Tags: php, button, click

I need to make a delete button that only the admin can see. The button needs to delete an item in my database but I'm having troubles with the last part.

I used this code to create the button and to call the delete function when it's clicked

```
if ($_SESSION['UserID'] == 1) {
    echo '<button name="featureDelete"> Delete </button>' . '<br>';
    if (isset($_POST['featureDelete'])) {
        $deleteFeature = $feature->Delete($row);
    }
}
```

And this is my delete function in my class

```
public function Delete($row)
{
    $db = new db();
    $sql= "DELETE FROM features WHERE FeatureID ='".$row['FeatureID']."'";
    $db->conn->query($sql);
}
```

So I can see the button, but when I click it nothing happens, I even tried echo'ing something, but didn't get a result. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok missing `<form>`, but, where is defined `$row` ?

Comment: it's defined earlier on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no form. Only a button.

```
echo '<form method="post"><button name="featureDelete"> Delete </button></form>' . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a form for your button :

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="featureDelete" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: That was it, thanks alot!. Still something wrong with my query though, since it now deletes all the data that was stores in 'features'. But thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a form and send the variable $row.

Try:

```
<form method="POST"> <input type="text" value="1" name="row" /> <button type="submit" >DELETE</button></form>
```

And then, on the PHP, before executing the SQL

```
$row = $_POST['row'];
```